# Google maps not loaded in webview remaining other sites getting loaded

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to load google maps inside a web view.

```
String mapPath = "https://maps.google.com/?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=29.301969,56.513672&t=h&z=4";

    home_location_map = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_location_map);
    home_location_map.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    home_location_map.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    home_location_map.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    home_location_map.loadUrl(mapPath);
   //home_location_map.loadUrl("www.google.com");
```

The commented line works perfectly fine. But google maps is not loaded and screen remains blank. What can be the reason ? I had tried almost every solution available for it.

I had given permission in manifest file too.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Try to encode the URL: `URLEncoder.encode(mapPath, "UTF-8")`

Comment: @surlac Still same result :(. Am getting this msg : " Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid"

Comment: I notice that you try to load a whole map on the website `https://maps.google.com/?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=29.301969,56.513672&t=h&z=4`. You can try to use map Intent to do that. For more details, please refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps)